# How do I connect AppDelegate in XCode 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I just learned my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` was not being triggered. Doing a search around here, it seems I need to set my `AppDelegate` as a `delegate` of my main window.

The answers here explain how to do it in IB with main.xib. I'm on Xcode 4.3.2 using storyboard. How do I do the same in storyboard?

Thanks.

Comment: same is in Xcode 3.2 or 5.1 or 4.2. Xcode is only an IDE and not the language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You don't set the app delegate as a delegate of the main window but the shared UIApplication instance (in the other case it would be called window delegate). You'd better change your `main()` function; call

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegateClass");
```

instead of the default

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

call.

Also note that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is deprecated. You may need to transition to the new

```
application:didFinishWithLaunching:
```

delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Currently my main.m reads `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SMAppDelegate class]));`, which actually was the default when I created a project. I'm still not seeing `applicationDidFinishLaunching` being triggered.

Comment: Test findings.. I created a new simple project, and found that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` doesn't exist at all. I moved my `NSLog` into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and everything is working as expecte. Maybe it was a stupid edit I made or something.. thanks.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you used a deprecated method. Updated my answer.